# jquery prevent from dragging selection text

Tags: jquery, css, selection, highlight

I would like in css or jquery to prevent the user to drag a selected text

Here in this picture we can select the text, and copy it, ok.
But then, I don't want the ability to drag this text around.

I want when I start to click & drag on the selected content, to start a new selection highlight.
[image]

I have manage to disable the drag of the text by doing that:

```js
$('.content').on('dragstart', function (e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

But then it does'nt start a new selection.

EDIT: here a video of the problem
https://youtu.be/zya0L67Rm2w

it's a basic feature, but I want to be able to disable it, for ergonomy reason. I have a block of code, and I want that block of code to be easly selectable, and no draggable

Thanks.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? When I tried your code in Chrome, I was able to create new selections and still not be able to drag them.

Comment: In The last version of chrome

Answer (score 0):

If you preventDefault on the .content class, it works to stop dragging that starts only on the content block/selection, but as you demonstrated you can still click and drag from the whitespace around it to start a basic text dragging. It's built into the browser/operating system to behave this way.

To stop it, you also need to prevent dragging on the HTML/BODY tag (or on the page container tag, if you have a bigger container):

```
$('html, body').on('dragstart', function (e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: unfortunatly, it doesn't start a new selection after that. It does stop the drag (like in my exemple), but it disable also the new selection

Comment: When it starts the drag, the script cancels the event, which means the browser is now doing nothing (and definitely not starting a new selection). To start a new selection, you have to click and select again. There's no way around this that I know of to stop all text dragging without requiring a second click to start a second selection.

Comment: I already saw a website who does exactly what I want.
Here it is:
http://thegamedev.guru/unity-addressables-learn-workflows/
In the code section (scroll down a bit), we can select twice without having that unwanted drag.

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to accomplish by blocking click/drag of text? Even in your example page, people can still select text, copy, and paste it elsewhere. Stopping click/drag doesn't stop the ability to copy code out of that box on thegamedev.guru. Otherwise, that site has a complex onDragStart function that is probably doing something on like 6506 of this file:
http://thegamedev.guru/wp-content/plugins/wp-codemirror-block/vendor/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js?ver=5.40.2

Comment: It's for ergonomy reason: i WANT peaple to copy/past text in a block of code, but I don't want to be able to select & drag. It's for user convenience